# CiviMail error: Could not find entry named in civicrm_mail_settings

Tags: civimail, extension

I would like to know how I have to add an email in my domain

I have the following error:

**Failed to connect
Could not find entry named in civicrm_mail_settings (See log for more details.)**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is information about how to configure CiviCRM to send email in the System Administrator Guide: [Email system confirguration](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/).